# Why can't you access this array with index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Why does this array have a `length` property of 0? And as a follow up to that question, why can't you access an item in this array with an index value?

Consider the following:

```
var box = [];

box['material'] = 'cardboard';
box['size'] = 'small';

box.length; //0
console.log(box);
//[ material: 'cardboard', size: 'small' ]

box[0]; //undefined
```

However, when I do the following:

```
var box = [];
box['0'] = true;
box['1'] = 'cardboard';
box['2'] = 'some value';

box.length; //3
box[0];// true
```

Why does it output the correct length in this case, since '0' is a string and not a number and access the correct item with the 0 index?

Comment: I don't have an exact answer, and this question is probably a duplicate, but when you make the assignment `box['material'] = 'cardboard'` you're not actually storing anything into an index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, the length of an array is always one more than the largest numeric (integer) property name. Arrays can have properties whose names are not numeric, but they don't count towards the length of the array (and they are ignored in some other important situations).

Object property names are *always* strings, but strings that are non-negative integer values when interpreted as numbers are special in arrays. Accessing properties with numeric values works because the numbers are first converted to strings; thus `box[0]` and `box['0']` do exactly the same thing.

Comment: E.g. the `length` property doesn't count itself.

Comment: Are array actually arrays or objects? i hear some say numeric arrays are arrays but associative arrays are objects; so what's going on?

Comment: @Novice arrays are objects, but the behavior of the `.length` property is special. JavaScript doesn't really have an "associative array" type.

Comment: In javascript arrays, array indices are not property names. I think the real answer is "JavaScript properties that begin with a digit cannot be referenced with dot notation; and must be accessed using bracket notation." (from [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)) So in javascript there isn't a way of referencing an integer index using a string, which makes the last statement in your answer true.

Comment: @AliNaciErdem that is not correct; array indexes are **definitely** property names. All property names are strings; other values used as property names are *converted* to strings first.

Comment: @AliNaciErdem try this in your browser console: `Object.keys([0,0,0])`

Comment: Yes, you are right. Array indices also seem to work like property names even though they differ in their internal workings. There seem to be always a "property name mapping phase" if you will :) Property name is converted into an array index in case of an array and into a dictionary-like entry in case of an object. Do you agree @pointy?

Comment: Yes, what matters is that the `.length` property is automatically updated for property names that are numeric (integers).

Answer (score 0):

when setting box['material'] it creates a property called 'material' with value 'cardboard'. this doesn't add a element to the list!

you need to use .push() or asign the index you want.

also, the '0' string is cased to a number, so obj['0'] and obj[0] is the same (not just for 0, this happens for all numbers)

Answer (score 0):

I think you’re confusing objects with arrays. While arrays are indeed objects in javascript, that doesn’t help us here.

What you are trying to instantiate is an associative array with key-value pairs `“material”->“cardboard”, “size”->“small”`. However, such a datastructure does not exist in javascript. Array must only have integers as indexes, as in

```
box = [];
box[0] = 'material';
box[1] = 'someValue';
```

The reason why your code (which only *seems* to be an associative array)

```
box = [];
box['0'] = true;
box['1'] = 'cardboard';
```

works is because of implicit type conversion. Because you’ve declared `box` to be an array, a string is not valid in this position, so javascript quietly converts it into an integer, so you again get a plain, boring, integer-indexed array as above.

What you can do, though, is create an `object` with attributes. So you might, for example, state

```
box = {};           // box is now an object
box.size = 'small'; // box now has an attribute called “size”
                    // which has the (string) value “'small'”
box.material = 'cardboard';
```

or at one go using the notation for object literals:

```
box = {
    size: 'small',
    material: 'cardboard'
};
```

This is the closest you can get to associative arrays in javascript. Note that objects do not have a length. If you want to access the number of *attributes* they have, you have to use `Object.keys(box).length`. To iterate over the keys, use

```
for(var key in box){
    console.log('value of ' + key + ' is ' + box[key])
}
```

Note the array-like notation here, but remember: You’re dealing with objects, not arrays, though dealing with them looks similar. Since box is of type object, you will not only get the attributes you have defined yourself, but also any attributes which are defined for every object. To get only the keys you put in there yourself, use

```
for (var key in box) {
    if (box.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

If you need to add keys, i.e. attributes at runtime, use (for example)

```
//supposing that box was instantiated as above
var listOfBoxAttributes = ['shape', 'color', 'weight'];
for(var i in listOfBoxAttributes)
    box[listOfBoxAttributes[i]] = undefined;
```